# Replace text of items under a column in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need some help with some code I made to replace the text of an item in a listView.

I want to replace all items under column 4 of my listView. Heres an example string of an item in column 4: `<span class="stat">0.58`

Anyways here is what I wrote to replace the text  in my listView but it isn't working:

```
foreach (ListViewItem i in listViewClickbank.Items)
{
    if (i.SubItems[3].Text.Contains("span"))
    {
        i.Text.Replace("<span class=", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String.Replace` method returns the new string.  It doesn't alter the original one.  Also, you are changing the `Text` of the item (the first column), rather than the fourth column.  Try this instead:

```
i.SubItems[3].Text = i.SubItems[3].Text.Replace("<span class=", "");
```

Comment: Too awesome! Thank you for the help man, I didnt see that mistake :)